# How to map "ç" to another key?

Tags: 10.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have a new keyboard and it has an <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key smaller than my previous keyboard, right next to it there is this key "**ç**" and I always hit it when trying to hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

I don't use this **ç** key, so is there a way I could map it to the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key?

I am using Ubuntu 10.04, the keyboard is a genius slimstar 110.

**Update:**

I solved it using `sudo xmodmap -e "keysym 51 = KP_Enter"`, but will that survive a restart?

Comment: Put it in a new file called `~/.Xmodmap`.

Answer (score 2):

Update:

I solved it using sudo xmodmap -e "keysym 51 = KP_Enter", but will that survive a restart? `Uoplem Dec 19 '11 at 4:37`

Put it in a new file called ~/.Xmodmap. – `enzotib Dec 19 '11 at 6:51`

Comment: Or run  `xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap` after changing the keysym. Don't run xmodmap with sudo though; it doesn't make it work any better than it already does.

Comment: @geirha want to edit that into the question? I haven't a clue, I'm just trying to move good answers from the comments as part of clean up week.